# LEFT JOIN  returning empty result set

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I'm having a small logic issue with joins. I have a database for answering answer. The schema is:

```
Question
question_id
question_text

Answers
answer_id
question_id
answer_text

User Responses
user_id
answer_id
question_id
```

I am trying to find questions that a user has not already answered but I keep getting null responses. The query is below:

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN responses ON questions.question_id = responses.question_id 
WHERE user_id != '1'
```

Where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a separate `Responses` table in instead of entering the `user_id` in the `Question` and `Answers` tables?

Comment: @Clodoaldo : its not a good db practice at all... because 1 question can have multiple responses..

Comment: @Chandresh Then there will be `1` question to `N` answers. What is the problem?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Questions, Answers and Responses are all different. I don't think there's anything wrong with his schema. For example, Question: What is 2+2? Answers: 4, 5, 6. Response: 4. Think of it in terms of a multiple-choice; answers are the possible answers. Responses are each user's response.

Answer (score 2):

Try a LEFT JOIN with IS NULL

```
SELECT q.question_id FROM questions q
    LEFT JOIN responses r ON q.question_id = r.question_id AND r.user_id = 1
WHERE r.question_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Why is the user_id inside of the join?

Comment: @DevinDixon It will work either way as a JOIN condition or as part of the WHERE clause. When it's in the JOIN condition it means MySQL filter on that condition before it JOINs which may make it more efficient. To find out which performs better for you you'd need to benchmark them against your data.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql and I'm finding it does not where in the WHERE clause and only in the JOIN clause, which is why I asked.

Comment: @DevinDixon Ah ok. In which case I have removed the MySQL tag from your question as it's not relevant. I don't know PGsql so can't comment on that I'm afraid.

Comment: @DevinDixon: This *does* work in PostgreSQL. Not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: r.user_id =1 in the WHERE CLAUSE returns an empty result set. But r.user_id =1 in the JOIN CLAUSE returns the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the questions which are not answered by the User with user id 1

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN responses ON questions.question_id = responses.question_id 
WHERE responses.question_id IS NULL AND user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a left join, rather use a subquery. This is how you'd do it in MS SQL - you may need to tweak for MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id NOT IN (
    SELECT question_id FROM responses WHERE user_id = 1
)
```

Left Joins where you need to check a value that is in the right table can cause you headaches. I find it easier and more reliable to query this way for this particular type of query.

Comment: Which is faster? That way or left joins?

Comment: Obviously LEFT JOIN...SubQuery is not recommended until & unless no any other options..

Comment: @Chandresh - Obviously? Can you point me to the article from the MySQL team or research done that shows that Left Join always performs better than Sub Queries? I'd be really interested in learning why.

Comment: @DevinDixon - first get everything working, then optimize for performance only if you are having performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is an `EXISTS` semi-join.

```
SELECT *
FROM   questions q
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM   responses r
   WHERE  r.question_id = q.question_id
   AND    r.user_id = 1
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN responses ON questions.question_id = responses.question_id AND 
user_id != '1'
```

using where at end will cause to filter both tables resulting null.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select * 
from Question
where question_id not in (select question_id from Responses where user_id=1)
```